# Error in parsing json in python

Tags: python, json

Trying to parse this json in python

```
'''[{"accountName":"London\"Paris\"Geneva","accountId":"1664800781","isActive":true,"timeZone":"Asia/Jerusalem","currency":"ILS"}]'''
```

gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicode_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    parsed_json = json.loads(json3)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

whereas this json parses fine(adding extra '\')

```
'''[{"accountName":"London\\"Paris\\"Geneva","accountId":"1664800781","isActive":true,"timeZone":"Asia/Jerusalem","currency":"ILS"}]'''
```

with this code:

```
import json

json3 = '''[{"accountName":"London\\"Paris\\"Geneva","accountId":"1664800781","isActive":true,"timeZone":"Asia/Jerusalem","currency":"ILS"}]'''

parsed_json = json.loads(json3)
print json.dumps(parsed_json)
print parsed_json[0]['accountName']
```

But the output has me confused,
json.dumps() output

```
[{"currency": "ILS", "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem", "accountId": "1664800781", "isActive": true, "accountName": "London\"Paris\"Geneva"}]
```

actual accountName string

```
London"Paris"Geneva
```

How can I get `London"Paris"Geneva` in the json string?

Comment: How are you getting the data? Are you typing it in at an interactive prompt, or are you reading it from a file?

Comment: have you tried marking your string as raw? (`r'''bla'''` instead of `'''bla'''`)

Comment: @BryanOakley I'll get the data from a GET call, but for illustration it's just a string in the file right now

Comment: why are you adding extra '\' ?

Comment: _"but for illustration it's just a string in the file right now"_ - then that's your problem. What you're typing isn't precisely the same as what you are getting from the GET. You need to be absolutely precise. Try using a raw string so that the parser isn't treating backslashes as escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is called [character escaping](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). The parser is indeed working as intended; this is a common topic across most programming languages.

In your particular example, you are trying to use double quotes `"` within a value, which itself is enclosed within double quotes, like this:

```
'accountName': "London'Paris'Geneva",
```

To parse the string you expected, I would do something like this:

```
import json

json3 = '''[{"accountName": "London\'Paris\'Geneva", "accountId": "1664800781", "isActive": "true", "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem", "currency": "ILS"}]'''

parsed_json = json.loads(json3)
print (json.dumps(parsed_json))
print (parsed_json[0]['accountName'])
```

which produces the following output:

```
[{"currency": "ILS", "timeZone": "Asia/Jerusalem", "accountId": "1664800781", "isActive": "true", "accountName": "London'Paris'Geneva"}]
London'Paris'Geneva
```

Comment: Why does escaping double quote with a single backslash throw error in the first example? Whereas escaping with double backslash gives me `"London\"Paris\"Geneva"` whereas I want `"London"Paris"Geneva"`

Comment: Because you are using double quotes (") to separate values. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Preceding quotes with a `\` in a string literal is called escaping it, and tells the parser that you actually mean the string contains a quote, not to end the string there. Python has two other options for that: Use a different type of quote to wrap the string, or put `r` before the string which means roughly "assume that all quotes and backslashes are already escaped."

What's happening here is that the `json` module is re-escaping things in the output for consistency - if you load some `json`, dump it, and then load what you dump, it shouldn't change. `json` will then read that string, so you need the double-backslash so that the quotes get escaped again then. If `json` loads a string-literal containing a double-quote, the string-literal will need to have the quote preceded by `\\\`, be wrapped with single-quotes and have the quote preceded by `\\`, or else be a raw string.

Simplifying your example, three things would work:

```
test = "{\"accountName\": \"London\\\"Paris\\\"Geneva\"}"
```

(escape all internal quotes, and also escape the backslashes around "Paris" for later re-escaping)

and

```
test = '{"accountName": "London\\"Paris\\"Geneva"}'
```

(Using single-quotes means you don't need to escape the double-quotes, but you still need to escape the backslashes because you *can* escape things even when you don't *need* to, and you don't actually want to in this case.)

and

```
test = r'{"accountName": "London\"Paris\"Geneva"}'
```

(Using a raw string means you're telling it nothing is escaped, so you can use backslashes safely, but you still need to use single quotes to wrap it so that the double-quotes don't end it)

All three of which actually represent a string containing `"` around the key and value, with `\` before the `"` in the middle of the value: `'{"accountName": "London\"Paris\"Geneva"}'` but which will generally be printed as `\\` instead of `\` so that you know it's a literal `\`rather than an escape on the following character. That is to say:

```
>>> print test
'{"accountName": "London\\"Paris\\"Geneva"}'
>>> print test[23]
'\\'
```

The `\\` is a representation on screen that takes two characters of space, but represents internally a single `\` character.

The output of `json.loads(test)`, then, is a `dict`:

```
{'accountName': 'London"Paris"Geneva'}
```

And `json.dumps(json.loads(test)) == test`

If you want `json` to dump that again, it needs to re-escape those quotes to keep things readable - if it didn't put the backslashes back in, trying to re-load that would result in an error when it hit an un-escaped quote too early. You won't be able to get `json` to dump a string that includes unescaped quotes in the middle of a string, because it is required to always dump readable JSON text which can be loaded to result in the same structure it was told to dump. If you must have the actual string contain double-quotes, your options are either:

1. Dump it with `json`, then process it afterwards to remove the backslashes. If the output string there is still `test`, you'd run `test.replace(r'\"', r'"')`
2. Process your object in some way other than by `json.dumps()`, in which case you can do it more or less however you like.

Either way, though, you won't be able to read the result as JSON again without adding those back in.

Comment: `json.dumps` should have been used on the dict `{'accountName': 'London"Paris"Geneva'}` to create the JSON data, in the first place.